# Hello World console application crashes in ConEmu

Tags: visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2015, conemu

When executing a newly built "Hello World" console application in CMD or PowerShell inside [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (frames and tabulates everything), the application will fail with "MyApp has stopped working" *after* printing "Hello World".

Execution in a regular CMD/PowerShell works fine.

Setup:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2015
- ConEmu 150816
- .Net 4.5.2

Problem details/signature:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   PerforceSSOClient.exe
Application Version:    1.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  55e5acb4
Fault Module Name:  nvd3d9wrap.dll
Fault Module Version:   9.18.13.3182
Fault Module Timestamp: 5280d7e2
Exception Code: c00000fd
Exception Offset:   0000583d
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1030
Additional Information 1:   c859
Additional Information 2:   c859befd7e6cd7469e4e4ec59e24adda
Additional Information 3:   fd58
Additional Information 4:   fd581380868e58459acc52bac65d582b
```

Comment: Do you have `NVIDIA corporation\CoProcManager` folder in your `program files`?

Comment: Yes, I have it. It contains three dll-files.

Comment: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/272

Answer (score 0):

The crash is caused by the nVIDIA driver dll `nvd3d9wrap.dll`. You use the driver version 331.82. Try to use the latest driver `355.82`:

32Bit: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90493/en-us
64Bit: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90494/en-us

Comment: I tried updating the Nvidia driver and ConEmu, but the result is the same.

Comment: follow the link from @Maximus and try the latest test builds.